# Return an unencoded JsonResult from MVC3 controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I want my controller to return a JsonResult such as:

```
return Json(new { test = "<div>Hello World!</div>" });
```

But the above is sent to the browser as:

```
"\u003cdiv\u003eHello World!\u003c/div\u003e"
```

How can I return the response unencoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to return HTML using a method whose purpose is to return Json.

You may want to take a look at `Content()` method and its overloads.

```
return Content("<div>Hello World!</div>");
```

- [Content(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470588.aspx)
- [Content(string, string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492713.aspx)
- [Content(string, string, Encoding)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505216.aspx)

Comment: I'm trying to return a JSON array. One element in that array will be an HTML string. The above example excluded the rest of the array for clarity.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. Anyway, return HTML from the controller is wrong, return HTML inside JSON from the controller is doubly wrong. HTML belongs to the views, no matter what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106676/how-to-get-html-returned-from-actionresult-in-controller) answer. Once again, I want to reinforce the idea that you must be doing something wrong to want to return HTML from a controller

Comment: The controller isn't generating HTML. I'm just passing a partial view to jQuery for a partial page update. It actually is a view I'm returning. I just want to pass it to jquery in order to perform a partial page update. 

This is a somewhat common pattern.

Comment: http://blog.janjonas.net/2011-06-18/aspnet-mvc3-controller-extension-method-render-partial-view-string

Answer (score 1):

There is an HTML helper 
`@HTML.Raw()`

which would work like you need. You'll need to pull a couple tricks though to get an instance of it in your controller.

EDIT: You just need to populate an instance with the correct data.

```
 var html = new HtmlHelper(new ViewContext(ControllerContext, null, new ViewDataDictionary(), new TempDataDictionary()), new ViewPage());
```

Give that a try...

Comment: Thanks. I know about HTML.Raw but I've never used it in a controller. An example would be great.

Comment: @Mark S. I'll try to find some code I wrote. It's been a while

Comment: @Mark S See if that gives you a valid HTML helper object to work with to call Raw() on.  You'll need to pass in the orig context which is in the Controller itself.